# «Ну ты скажи!» — самостоятельное употребление

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Можно ли употреблять «*Ну ты скажи!*» как отдельную фразу для выражения сильного удивления, как синоним «*Да что ты говоришь!*», «*Да ты что!*» и тому подобных?

Насколько я помню, можно, но что-то я засомневался, хотелось бы услышать независимое мнение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит "можно"? Так говорят, в устной речи точно поймут. Поймут и в письменной, а если боитесь, что не поймут, добавьте какую-нибудь ремарку: удивился, удивлённо воскликнул, всплеснул руками и т.п. Да и так из контекста должно быть понятно.